# Mysterious winamp ratings that come from nowhere

Tags: winamp

Winamp gives the option to rate songs.  This is not a new feature.  Everytime I would reinstall Windows and reinstall Winamp my ratings would all go away as expected, and I would have to re-rate everything.

However, this time when I reinstalled Winamp, after using it for a few days, songs would appear in my top rated list as being rated.  Some of these I remember rating a long time ago before I reinstalled Windows, and some of these I don't remember ever rating.

Where are these ratings coming from?

Comment: Are the ratings changing with songs that you are currently playing?  Could it be related to play count by any chance?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with play count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the songs freshly ripped or are they recoevered from a backup? Often times music file formats have the user's rating contained within it.

Why the delay? It likely took WinAmp time to parse all the files and rebuild it's rating database which I'm assuming it uses.

Alternatively, it could be storing the ratings in to a service of some sort on the internet, and retrieve the ratings.

Comment: Ratings can be stored in the ID3 tags of mp3 files.